# Trying to encrypt and decrypt code-beginner

Tags: c, encryption, bit-manipulation

So this is a Bit maniuplation excercise that im confused about how they convert letters to the numbers, i think these arent binary so i dont know what they mean.
Can anyone suggest an approach?

> Here's two examples of encryption: "cats" and "kittens".
>
> Pairs: "ca ts"  "ki tt en s_" (_ represents a space) into ints: 25441
>   29811  27497 29812 25966 29472 XOR with 31337: 6408 3610  4352 3613
>   7943 2377

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal quintet for each couple of letters is just the decimal representation of the concatenated hex values of the characters in ASCII, eg:

```
"ca" = 0x63 0x61 = 0x6361 = 25441
```

Same story for the XOR key which is

```
31337 = 0x7A69
```

Indeed

```
0x6361 ^ 0x7A69 = 0x1908 = 6408 in decimal
```

Comment: How do u do the last part going from 0x636 to 25441

Answer (score 2):

The Ascii value of 'c' is 99 and the Ascii value of 'a' is 97. Treat these as digits in base 256. Then "ac" would be 99*256 + 97 = 25441. Note that in C, char is a number type, so 'c' *is* 99, etc.